# CSS attribute settings-- am I missing something?

Tags: css

Doing a review of someone's CSS file and I came across this bit.  He's a fine CSS designer so before saying anything I wanted to see if there's something I'm not following?

In the snippet below he appears to be redefining a few attributes by mistake-- namely, the text-decoration and color attributes for the hover and active states on an href:

```
.myClass
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 10px 15px;
}

a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited, 
a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    font-size:11px;
    color: #42382c;
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height:16px;
}

a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It lets him code by difference.

First he defines styles for link, visited, hover and active, which are mostly the same as each other.

Then below that he over-rides that in two particular cases.

Code can be shorter this way, and also reflect the fact that those four are mostly the same, right in the code (self-documentation).

If you enforced a no-duplication rule, it would either look like:

```
a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited, 
a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:16px;
}

a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited {
    color: #42382c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Or like:

```
a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:16px;
    color: #42382c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:16px;
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The latter duplicates rules, and the former is less concise, and less-self documenting; his version says "exactly like each other except...".

Comment: @MystereMan No, they all refer to a specific class of link, in different states. There's no functional difference between any of them, but the code in the question is shorter and more self-documenting. If I was the reviewer I'd change the examples in my answer to look like that in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and to everyone else who contributed too.

Answer (score 3):

That is just because he otherwise needs to write one of the following you do the same:

```
a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited {
    font-size:11px;
    color: #42382c;
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height:16px;
}

a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:16px;
}
```

or

```
a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited,
a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:16px;
}

a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited, {
    color: #42382c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And he thought his way was shorter, prettier and/or more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of it as duplicate, just think of it as an override.  He is just overriding the styling in certain circumstances.  The way he wrote it is slightly less markup, see below where it is actually longer when not "duplicating"

```
.myClass
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 10px 15px;
}

a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited, 
a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:16px;
}

a.linkWhatsThis:link, 
a.linkWhatsThis:visited {
    color: #42382c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a.linkWhatsThis:hover, 
a.linkWhatsThis:active {
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it is duplicated. It's just because the author of that CSS chose to collate the styles that way. Color and line-height are shared, so it's either that or make more separaate rules to cover each case. Whichever way you do it there's duplication - either of rules or selectors. What matters is which rule wins out in the end.